# Multiple groupings without SPD

Tags: grouping-sets

our client wants multiple groupings in a Sharepoint 2010 list. Aprox 6 grouping headers. Unfortunatelly we are not allowed to use SPD. is there any way that i can create multiple groupings without SPD?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata navigation. It's not exactly grouping, it's filtering. But you can use a combination of the default group by and metadata navigation to achieve the purpose.

Metadata navigation is available for choice columns and taxonomy columns.